# Scanner detected with sane-find-scanner, but not with scanimage -L or sudo scanimage -L

Tags: scanner, sane, fujitsu-siemens

I have a Fujitsu ScanSnap S1300i. I compiled SANE from source. When I run `sane-find-scanner`, the following output is given:

```
sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. 
If the result is different from what you expected, first make sure your scanner 
is powered up and properly connected to your computer.
No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure 
that you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x04c5, product=0x128d) at libusb:002:004  
Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by SANE.
Try scanimage -L and read the backend's
manpage.

Not checking for parallel port scanners.
Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports can't be detected by this program.
You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. 
Once you found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as necessary.
```

However, when I run `scanimage -L` or `sudo scanimage -L` the following output is given:

```
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different. 
Check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). 
Please read the documentation which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

Also, I added an entry to `/etc/sane.d/fujitsu.conf` for the ScanSnap S1300i.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I see [on the official sane page](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html), the ScanSnap S1300 uses the `epjitsu`, not the `fujitsu` backend. You could try moving the configuration entry from `fujitsu.conf` to `epjitsu.conf` file in the same folder.

I'm not sure what exactly are the differences between the S1300 and S1300i, so you may have to extract the `*.nal` firmware file from the Fujitsu Windows driver like it says in the header of both `fujitsu.conf` and `epjitsu.conf` files in `/etc/sane.d/`, if you haven't done that already.

**Update**
I just remembered when I built sane from source because I needed the new version for my scanner to function, I had to create a new udev rule for the scanner to be usable.

Created a new file in /etc/udev/rules.d called 40-libsane.rules and add the following line to the file:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="AAAA", ATTRS{idProduct}=="BBBB", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

Replace the AAAA and BBBB with the IDs of your scanner. You can see them by typing `lsusb` (actually it's the same IDs you said you used to create a new entry in fujitsu.conf).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I don't have an installation of Windows or OSX, so I can't extract the .nal file from the driver. Is there a way to do it without installing the driver? I have the installation CD that came with the scanner on my desk.

Comment: It says that the file usually resides inside a .cab file. You could try searching the folders and archives on the CD.

Also see my edited answer, I just remembered something else I needed to do.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I got it working! I borrowed a friend's computer that's running Vista and installed the driver on it. I transferred a .nal file titled 1300i_0D12.nal to /usr/share/sane/epjitsu/ and added the appropriate lines in epjitsu.conf.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! If you want, send an e-mail to the address in the header of the epjitsu.conf so that they can include the support for your scanner in future versions of sane!

Comment: Does not work with backend 1.0.22 (starts paperfeed and then halts in error) and current git snapshot (1.0.24git) segfaults. Could you supply the backend version (scanimage -V) or post a link to the backend (source or version) that works with this scanner?

Comment: You're right. IIRC, I had to compile sane-backends from source. My version is `scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.23git; backend version 1.0.23`. But now I see that on my other machine I have the version 1.0.23. I didn't test the scanner there, though.

Comment: @Crynix could you confirm that you were able to get your s1300i actually outputting scans? As I've had a similar experience to @petur and only get ```scanimage: sane_start: Error during device I/O``` when trying to scan using ```scanimage``` after compiling the current git HEAD of sane from src as well as the commit that matched the 1.0.23 release.

Comment: @Maks I definitely had it working. Later this week I'm going to set up the scanner again. I'll give both you and petur a rundown on how I did it.

Comment: @Crynix thanks that would be great as I've tried compiling sane backends from src from different versions in git and no luck. I should also mention that I'm using the pre-installed sane from 12.04 though I don't think that would make a difference. And I assume also you used the 1300i_0D12.nal firmware file?

Comment: @ZachLatta I know its been a while but did you ever get a chance to setup your scanner again and note down how you got it working?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/567863/s1300i-scanner-issues-under-ubuntu-16-04-using-sane for the answer to a similar question.

Comment: I've got the same problem but for the ix100 which is said to use the fujitsu driver; furthermore, it only fails to work for the version *I* compiled and not the precompiled `scanimage`.

Comment: https://github.com/stevleibelt/scansnap-firmware/blob/master/1300_0C26.nal
https://github.com/stevleibelt/scansnap-firmware

This person has put the firmwares on github.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a pretty esoteric addition, but i had the same problem and non of the solutions that i found worked for me. The strange thing was that the scanner (scansnap 1300) worked fine in `gscan2pdf`, it just wasnt showing on `scanimage -L` and (therefore?) `scanbd` failed to register a thread for the button activity. At some point i fired

```
SANE_DEBUG_DLL=3 scanimage -L
```

to analyse the output.. and for some strange reason than the problem was gone. And `scandb` also started working after that. Kind of a heisenbug (one that doesnt happen when you look). :shrug:

I also fired

```
udevadm control --reload-rules;udevadm trigger
```

before (but im pretty sure i already did that before and it didnt helped, i also restarted once after adding the udev rule).
Maybe someone finds this helpful