# Ubuntu 17.10 and Samsung SCX-4624F Scanner not working

Tags: scanner, 17.10

After I installed Ubuntu 17.10, Samsung SCX-4624F Scanner stopped working. What is strange after many tries I scanned one page but couldn't repeat this. After system reboot scanimage -L listed the scanner once and then scanner disappeared.

Comment: [related](https://askubuntu.com/q/178833/184892)

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1707352

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that in [SANE](http://www.sane-project.org/) 1.0.27 released in May 2017 had some USB fix disabled (printer/scanner with USB 2.0 has problems with USB 3.0 port).

It is possible to enable the fix with the new environment variable `SANE_USB_WORKAROUND=1`. After I added it to the `.bashrc`, Simple Scan started to work correctly.

Comment: Can you say exactly how you did this?

Comment: @Lolwhites add `export SANE_USB_WORKAROUND=1` to the `.bashrc` and see if it helps. In my case the fix helped. For some people the fix breaks communication with scanner therefore SANE developers decided the disable it. They thought that with new kernels it is not needed. And it turned out that is some cases it is still needed.

Comment: I added the line at the end but it didn't help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Lolwhites Does your scanner behavior is same as mine was? I mean: after reboot `scanimage -L` shows the scanner once but next `scanimage -L` does not show any scanners.

Comment: scanimage -L doesn't detect it but saner-find-scanner does.

Comment: @Lolwhites So you have a different problem https://askubuntu.com/q/178833/28004

Comment: life-saver! I used the following on the command-line:  
    'SANE_USB_WORKAROUND=1 simple-scan'

Answer (score 0):

Also for me the scanner is not working with samsung scx 4200 but for waiting the solution i find this way :

1) mache a script (for example scanner)

2) inside the script I insert this :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "insert path and file name extenction .pnm"
cd /home/YourHome(change this with your home)
read -p "insert:" PathName
echo $PathName
export SANE_USB_WORKAROUND=1
scanimage >$PathName
read -rsp "press a key to terminate" -n1 key
```

in this way I can scan my document and is working, off course I ave to convert then but this is not a problem

Comment: I find other solutiom, I open the terminal in home/username directory and I type xsane the window open and xsane work!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the Ubuntu application "Simple Scan" ?. It is in Ubuntu software center. It works for my old HP all in one Printer.

Comment: Same problem with Simple Scan.